# Почему не принимает индекс у массива python?

Tags: python

Есть функция:

```
def analize(text):
    result = ""
    alphabet = [33]
    for i in text:
        alphabet[ord(text[i])-1040] += 1
    for i in alphabet:
        result = result + str(alphabet[i]) + "-" + chr(alphabet[i + 1040])
```

Собственно, ругается, что у алфавита индекс в цикле не целочисленный.
Входные данные: Текст на русском.
Выходные данные: Частота букв.

Дополнено:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    alphabet[ord(text[i])-1040] += 1
```

Ругается на выход за пределы массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabet = [33]` создаёт список с одним элементом (числом `33`). Вы вероятно хотели: `count = [0] * 33`, чтобы создать список, который содержит частоты букв русского алфавита (поэтому `33` вероятно). `[0] * 33` это список из `33` элементов, каждый равный нулю.

Чтобы найти частоту символов в тексте, можно использовать [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count = Counter("мама мыла раму") 
>>> count
Counter({' ': 2, 'а': 4, 'л': 1, 'м': 4, 'р': 1, 'у': 1, 'ы': 1}) # Python 3
>>> count['а']
4
```

Answer (score 1):

в 4 строчке должно быть:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
```

или в 5 строке замени:

`text[i]`

на просто: `i`

Comment: Здесь тоже python3

Comment: я думаю, что твою проблему решил

Comment: Не работает что-то

Comment: можешь править и внизу ошибку написать

Comment: ты в массив alphabet вносишь данные? Просто у тебя в нем только число 33 с индексем 0.

Comment: Поправил описание. Нет, алфавит пустой, данные передаю в `text`

Comment: т.е. ты хочешь создать этот алфовит?

Comment: А, блин, а как ему тогда размер увеличить или он динамический?

Comment: если ты хочешь массив расширеть, то: `alphabet = [None for i in range(x)]` , где x число на которое оно расширется